# Select element CSS class to match Input element class

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, webkit, stylesheet

I found a nice style for my input elements but now I want to create a style that will look similar (or complementary) for my select elements.

I would like someone familiar with CSS styles to give me a class style I can use for my select elements.

Input Element Class:

```
input {
    background: 12px 11px no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f8 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: 12px 11px no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f8 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: 12px 11px no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f8 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: 12px 11px no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f8 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    background: 12px 11px no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7f7f8 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #222222;
    position: relative;
    height: 36px;
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #999999;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999999;
}
input:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #2392f3 inset, 0 -1px 0 #2392f3 inset, 1px 0 0 #2392f3 inset,     -1px 0 0 #2392f3 inset, 0 0 4px rgba(35, 146, 243, 0.5);
    outline: none;
    background: 12px 11px no-repeat, #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted a similar style to your inputs I'd suggest copying the code and applying it for `select` elements too. Of course you can modify the code to fit your needs, heres a basic example of what you could do:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PfQZE/)**

You just change:

```
input{}
```

..to..

```
select{}
```

Which applies the `CSS` too all `html` `select` elements.

Styling `select` inputs isn't always as straight foward as styling a text `input`, [for examples I suggest you read through this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

---

**EDIT:**

After doing some research, I found that it is almost impossible to style `select` `options` because they are rendered by the OS and not the browser.

This is the closest I could make the `select` match your `input`:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PfQZE/2/)**

This is using `jQuery` which is what I would initially suggest. I would also highly suggest checking out some `jQuery` plugins which can handle styling of the `select` inputs.

For example, I found this one:

http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/#.UXpaF7XvuCk

Which looks like it would work nicely with the style you're using.

Comment: Thank You. I actually tried that but figured it didn't work since I couldn't see gradient on background etc.  if you look at it on a white page its hard to see nice http://jsfiddle.net/PfQZE/1/

Comment: If you want I will try to make it look better for you?

Comment: Sure that would be great I am trying to get a consistent theme here http://donaldswofford.com.108-167-179-73.secure18.win.hostgator.com/ContactUs.aspx

Comment: That looks great is there anyway to put an arrow on there?